# How to create new app from already existed app flutter? By changing app name and package

Tags: flutter, build

I have already made an app, I want to create new app with different name/package.

> And I want to install both in same phone.

Currently what i have tried is to copy inner files of flutter app (all files inside top folder to new folder) and change app name and package name, I have used firebase so changed "google-service.json" file as well.

But still new app builds in old app. Old app replaced by new app (changed appname, package name).

If know pls help, (**Thanks**)

Comment: try using https://pub.dev/packages/rename or https://pub.dev/packages/change_app_package_name

Comment: afaik, you need to generate the new `google-service.json` for your new apk.